# discordjs v14 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm having an issue with this `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')`.

I have tried many things but none work. It does work when I don't work with module exports.

Here is my full code

```js
const { EmbedBuilder} = require('discord.js');

isstreaming = false;

module.exports = {
    name: "presenceUpdate",
    async execute(newPresence, client) {
        if (isstreaming === false) {
            if (newPresence.user.id === '151762679659233280') {
                const stream = newPresence.activities.find((activity) => activity.type === 1 && activity.name === 'Twitch');
                if (stream) {
                    const twitchEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
                        .setTitle(`${newPresence.user.username} is now live on Twitch!`)
                        .setColor('#6441A5')
                        .setDescription(`${stream.details}\n\nWatch now: ${stream.url}`);
                    
                    const channel = client.channels.get('1092538530879787160')
                    channel.send({ embeds: [twitchEmbed] })
                    isstreaming = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (newPresence.user.id === '151762679659233280') {
            const notstream = newPresence.activities.find((activity) => activity.type === 0);
            if (notstream) {
                isstreaming = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is full error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\john\Desktop\RastaFam discord bot\Events\twitch.js:17:53)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\john\Desktop\RastaFam discord bot\Handlers\eventHandler.js:23:59)
    at Client.emit (node:events:512:28)
    at PresenceUpdateAction.handle (C:\Users\john\Desktop\RastaFam discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\PresenceUpdate.js:37:19)
    at module.exports [as PRESENCE_UPDATE] (C:\Users\john\Desktop\RastaFam discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\PRESENCE_UPDATE.js:4:33)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\john\Desktop\RastaFam discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:352:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\john\Desktop\RastaFam discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:494:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\john\Desktop\RastaFam discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:328:10)
    at callListener (C:\Users\john\Desktop\RastaFam discord bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:290:14)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\john\Desktop\RastaFam discord bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:209:9)
```

Comment: thanks it did work sorry for the late reply work got in way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because [`presenceUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-presenceUpdate) takes two parameters (`oldPresence` and `newPresence`) and you only used the first one. So your `client` variable is actually the `presence` after the update and `newPresence` is the one before the update.

You'll probably need to use something like:

```js
async execute(oldPresence, newPresence, client) { /* ... */ }
```

You could also use `const channel = newPresence.client.channels.get('1092538530879787160')`.